# C++ out of range error, error described in the content below

Tags: c++

I'm getting a `std::out_of_range` exception running the code below.  Here is the exact error text:

> Unhandled exception at 0x7690A6E2 in Student Project.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::out_of_range at memory location 0x00AFF2BC.

I don't know what is wrong with my code.  Is it the way the vector is defined?  Is anything wrong with the syntax of the vector?

How can I fix the problem so that the exception no longer occurs?

```cpp
void Roster::parseInput(string rawInput){
    std::vector<string> dataHolders;
    std::stringstream inputSStream(rawInput);

    while (inputSStream.good())
    { // Parse the string on every comma
        string input;
        getline(inputSStream, input, ',');
        dataHolders.push_back(input);
    }

    string studentID = dataHolders.at(0);
    string firstName = dataHolders.at(1);
    string lastName = dataHolders.at(2);
    string email = dataHolders.at(3);
    int age = stoi(dataHolders.at(4)); 
    int DayInCourse1 = stoi(dataHolders.at(5));
    int DayInCourse2 = stoi(dataHolders.at(6));
    int DayInCourse3 = stoi(dataHolders.at(7));
    degreeProgram DegreeProgram = convert(dataHolders.at(8)); //(I was told this could be the problem)
    string personalInformation = dataHolders.at(9);

    add(studentID, firstName, lastName, email, age, DayInCourse1, DayInCourse2, DayInCourse3, 
    DegreeProgram, personalInformation);
}

degreeProgram Roster::convert(string str)
{ //Converting string type to enum

    if (str == "SECURITY") return  SECURITY;

    else if (str == "NETWORK") return NETWORK;

    else if (str == "SOFTWARE") return SOFTWARE;

    else return INVALID;
        
}
```

Comment: You were told that something is wrong, but not WHAT that something actually is? Odd.  Are you getting errors from the compiler? If so, what are they exactly?

Comment: Hi,  was told that the its wrong with the vector itself, at the line where i have brackets open saying this could be the problem.

Comment: Would it be an accurate guess that this code is part of a larger program that compiles, but throws an exception when run?  Your use of the phrase "was told" is vague and confusing.

Comment: So you have out_of_range exception or compilation error? Please copy and paste that into your question, so we know what you are asking about.

Comment: yes, i am new learning programming, not sure how to fully write the code here.

Comment: What does the value of `rawInput` look like?

Answer (score 2):

You are getting an `std::out_of_range` exception at runtime.  That is likely being raised by one of the [`dataHolders.at()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at) calls:

> If pos is not within the range of the container, an exception of type std::out_of_range is thrown.

Which means your `vector` does not hold as many string elements as you are expecting.  So double-check that the value of your `rawInput` parameter is correct.  You can check the `size()` of the `vector` after the loop is finished, before accessing the string elements, eg:

```cpp
while (...)
{
    ...
    dataHolders.push_back(input);
}

if (dataHolders.size() >= 10)
{
    string studentID = dataHolders[0];
    ...
}
else
{
    // dataHolders has too few strings, do something else!
    ...
}
```

On a side note, your `while` loop should look more like this instead:

```cpp
// Parse the string on every comma
string input;
while (getline(inputSStream, input, ','))
{
    dataHolders.push_back(input);
}
```

Comment: HI, my RAW-Input  doesn't have a value

Comment: Well, then your `vector` will end up being empty, so you should be getting the error on `dataHolders.at(0)`, not on `dataHolders.at(8)` as you originally indicated. Either way, the problem is not even in the code you have shown, it is actually in the code that is calling `parseInput()`, so go fix that instead. This is why it is important to create a [mcve] when asking questions here.

Comment: Hi, I'm still not able to figure out what could be the problem? is there a way someone can look up the entire file and see what is going on, Thanks

Comment: Like I said earlier, you would need to provide a [mcve]. Please edit your question to provide enough code for someone to reproduce your issue in their own compiler

Comment: My advice is to use a debugger like the one in Visual Studio. You can have it stop on the exact line where the out of bounds happens. When it does so you can inspect the variables to understand how you are out of bounds.

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: void parseInput(string rawInput); This is the code i have for parseInput()

Comment: That is a declaration, not an invokation. What does the code look like that is *calling* `parseInput()` passing it a string to parse? What does THAT code look like?

Answer (score 1):

I would say you need to make sure your dataHolders has the correct number of entries (10) before trying to read them.

Comment: I tried doing number of entries to 10, am i using stoi correctly

Comment: The problem is not with `stoi()`. Your `dataHolders` is likely not holding as many strings as you are expecting. Check its `size()` value after the `while` loop is finished.

Comment: just an update the degreeProgram is an enum

Comment: "*degreeProgram is an enum*" - That information is irrelevant to the issue at hand